# Angular 2 Communication between components on the same level

Tags: angular, events

Is there any way how to communicate between 2 components on the **same level** using event emmiters?

Please, see to comments in enclosed html snippet.

```html
<div class="custom-container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs">
      <app-entity-listing (associationShown)=" TO DO " [isFromRoot]="isFromRoot">


      <!-- I am emiting a boolean value  -->
      </app-entity-listing>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-5">
      <div class="right-column-wrapper">
        <div class="main-container">
          <app-create-entity-screen-no-association [isVisible]="true"></app-create-entity-screen-no-associatio


       <! -- Based on emitted value from the first component, I will be visible or not  -->
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: This requires a parent component to fulfil the communication between children. It depends on the case if the communication should be done this way or through a service.

Answer (score 0):

You can create parent component (PARENT) that holds information about visibility of child component (CHILD B). From another child component (CHILD A) you can change the visibility using EventEmitter. See picture and code bellow.

[image]

```
import { Component, ViewChild, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
  <div style='background: red; padding: 10px; margin: 10px;'>
    <app-parent></app-parent>
  </div>
  `,
})
export class AppComponent {
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-child-a',
  template: `
  <h3>CHILD A</h3>
  <button (click)='changeVisibility(true)'>Show</button>
  <button (click)='changeVisibility(false)'>Hide</button>
  `,
})
export class ChildAComponent {

  @Output() onVisibilityChanged = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

  changeVisibility(visible: boolean) {
    this.onVisibilityChanged.emit(visible);
  }

}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-child-b',
  template: `
  <h3>CHILD B</h3>
  `,
})
export class ChildBComponent {
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent',
  template: `
  <h3>PARENT</h3>
  <div style='background: green; padding: 10px; margin: 10px;'>
    <app-child-a (onVisibilityChanged)='onVisibilityChanged($event)'></app-child-a>
  </div>
  <div *ngIf=visible style='background: blue; padding: 10px; margin: 10px;'>
    <app-child-b></app-child-b>
  </div>
  `,
})
export class ParentComponent {

  visible = false;

  onVisibilityChanged(visible: boolean) {
    this.visible = visible;
  }

}
```